# JavaScript Array vs C# Array

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, arrays

What type of array is this JavaScript Array shown? 1-dimensional, 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional? Also what will be the exact representation of this array in C#?

```
var arr = new Array ([34.01843, -118.491046], [34.006673, -118.486562], [34.009714, -118.480296], [34.010408, -118.473215], [34.01521, -118.474889], [34.022502, -118.480124],
            [34.024423, -118.459868], [34.024885, -118.44871], [34.002368, -118.482828], [34.003791, -118.473001], [34.015922, -118.457422], [34.022147, -118.457894],
            [34.028904, -118.46725], [34.030114, -118.481326], [34.03143, -118.494029], [34.031643, -118.504758], [34.029616, -118.515058], [34.001834, -118.451414]);
```

The datatypes of values in this array is double.

Comment: Array of items which are each arrays consisting of 2 doubles.. `double[][] arr;`

Comment: and why there is a **php** tag???

Comment: 'double' isn't a JavaScript type. A JavaScript variable is not declared explicitly, it is inferred by the runtime. In your snippet the type will be inferred as 'Number'

Comment: As stated, the exact representation would be an array of arrays of doubles (double[][]), now it seems to me that you want to know something else otherwise you would not add the jquery tag. Do you want to know how to pass this type correctly to C# using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a jagged array, where each inner array is of length 2.

In C#, you could use:

```
var arr = new [] {
    new[]{34.01843, -118.491046}, new[]{34.006673, -118.486562}, new[]{34.009714, -118.480296},
    //...
};
```

which is a `double[][]`; however, you could also elect to use a `double[,]` instead (but it would have different semantics):

```
var arr = new [,] {
    {34.01843, -118.491046}, {34.006673, -118.486562}, {34.009714, -118.480296},
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically, it doesn't have an "exact representation" in c#, and it depends on how the data is serialized and deserialized at each end.

I'd venture that something like `List<Tuple<double,double>>` would be a more appropriate datatype at the c# end.

Comment: Since in the js you can push to the inner items, and the inner items only have indexed access - I would argue that `List<List<double>>` would be closer

Comment: Sure, but I'm working on the assumption that what's really being described is a list of pairs. I might be wrong.